# Deploy/debug app from VS 2019 to windows 10 mobile phone via USB

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-mobile, visual-studio-2019

I have some old windows 10 mobile phones, that I want to give a second life as a music device for my kids. Since I have Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise at my hands, I thought I try to create something myself.

Not I tried to create an UWP app and a Xamarin app and try to debug them on the phone (connected via USB, developer mode enabled, unlocked). But with both I get this error:

> DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '127.0.0.1' using Universal
>   Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode
>   is specified in the project debug settings. COMException ... HRESULT:
>   0x8007274D) [0x8007274D]

The apps are still in their initial state after creating the project, no modifications done. The settings for debugging are set to: Debug, ARM, Device

I had some experience with an older Visual Studio version and windows phone 7, back then it just worked and all the documents I could google up suggest, while there are new ways, it should still work via USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to develop Windows 10 Mobile App, you need to use Visual Studio 2017 and make sure the target version of the app is below 14393.

Visual Studio 2019 no longer supports deploying UWP apps on mobile phones.

Best regards.

Comment: Ok, that explains it. I will try again with 2017 and comment, if this works. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately with 2017 I get another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59825400/deploy-debug-app-to-windows-10-mobile-phone-via-usb

Comment: Judging from the error message, you may not have turned on the developer mode of your phone. Please turn on developer mode in phone settings-> updates and security

Comment: I already activated developer mode on the phone and made it visible for USB connections. Do I also have to turn it on on the pc? Because the developer settings on the PC keep popping up, when I try to start the project...

Comment: Yes, to develop UWP applications through Visual Studio, you need to enable developer mode on both development and deployment devices

Comment: FWIW, I can deploy and run sideload packages that target version 1803 (build 17134) and min version Creator Update (build 15063) from VS2017.