# Deploy/debug app to windows 10 mobile phone via USB

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, uwp

I'm trying to create an UWP app for some old windows 10 mobile phones and deploy/debug them via USB.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and have set the target version to Build 10586 ([to stay below 14393](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819233/deploy-debug-app-from-vs-2019-to-windows-10-mobile-phone-via-usb)).

When I try to debug (freshly created UWP blank app, settings: Debug, ARM, Device), the deployment fails with this error:

> DEP0100: Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled.
>   Could not obtain a developer license due to error 800704C7.

Just before the failure the developer settings of my local machine pop up, so I have the feeling it is trying to deploy to my local windows 10 machine instead of the phone.

Comment: have you activated [dev mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#accessing-settings-for-developers) on the phone? Have you selected "device" in the [dropdown list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps)?

Comment: Yes, dev mode is enabled on the phone, device discovery is enabled, and the Device is selected in the dropdown list.

Comment: Your local machine pop up the developer settings is because if you want to write software with Visual Studio on a computer, you need to enable Developer Mode on the development PC. It will enable you to debug them with VS2017. If you also enable Developer Mode on your local machine, will the same issue occur?